# Cannot create certain QML types in a singleton

Tags: qml, qt5

I have a QML singleton for use in styling defined as follows:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

QtObject {
    property ProgressBarStyle progressBarErrorStyle: ProgressBarStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            radius: 2
            color: "lightgray"
            border.color: "gray"
            border.width: 1
            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 20
        }
        progress: Rectangle {
            color: "orangered"
            border.color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to import the object and use it, however `progressBarErrorStyle` is always given the type `ProgressBarStyle_QMLTYPE_17`. If I change it to a `Rectangle`, then it is correctly typed as `QQuickRectangle`.

The `QtQuick.Controls.Styles` import defines `ProgressBarStyle`, and in QtCreator I'm not getting any syntax errors... so why is my object given the wrong type at runtime?

Comment: Can you please post the full example, with a main .qml file that shows how you're using this? Also, what type do you expect it to be?

Comment: The question you give seems irrelevant with title (like in XY problem). Anyway, `ProgressBarStyle_QMLTYPE_17` is correct type, you could check  `metaObject()->superClass()` to see that qml make another type. If you add any property to some object, qml will define a new metaobject, appending `_QMLTYPE_%d` or `_QML_%d`(qml file) sufix to its name. But unless you explicitly check it in C++, this should not a make a problem in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Component](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#details) as the property type:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Rectangle {
    property Component progressBarErrorStyle: ProgressBarStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            radius: 2
            color: "lightgray"
            border.color: "gray"
            border.width: 1
            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 20
        }
        progress: Rectangle {
            color: "orangered"
            border.color: "red"
        }
    }

    ProgressBar {
        id: progressBar

        NumberAnimation {
            target: progressBar
            property: "value"
            to: 1
            running: true
            duration: 2000
        }

        style: progressBarErrorStyle
    }
}
```

The components for styles are used in `Loader` items internally, which create instances of the components when they need to, just like delegates in Qt Quick's [ListView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#delegate-prop), for example.